# carbon-relay Replication across Datacenters

Tags: replication, graphite, graphite-carbon

I recently "inherited" a Carbon/Graphite setup from a colleague which I have to redesign. The current setup is:

- Datacenter 1 (DC1): 2 servers (server-DC1-1 and server-DC1-2) with 1 carbon-relay and 4 carbon caches
- Datacenter 2 (DC2): 2 servers (server-DC2-1 and server-DC2-2) with 1 carbon-relay and 4 carbon caches

All 4 carbon-relays are configured with a REPLICATION_FACTOR of 2, consistent hashing and **all** carbon-caches ( 2(DCs) * 2(Servers) * 4(Caches) ). This had the effect that some metrics exist only on 1 server (they probably were hashed to a different cache on the same server). With over 1 million metrics this problem affects about 8% of all metrics.

What I would like to do is a multi-tiered setup with redundancy, so that I mirror all metrics across the datacenters and inside the datacenter I use consistent hashing to distribute the metrics evenly across 2 servers.

For this I need help with the configuration (mainly) of the relays. Here is a picture of what I have in mind:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dtjGlhn.png]

The clients would send their data to the *tier1relay*s in their respective Datacenters ("loadbalancing" would occur on client side, so that for example all clients with an even number in the hostname would send to **tier1relay-DC1-1** and clients with an odd number would send to **tier1relay-DC1-2**).

The *tier2relay*s use consistent hashing to distribute the data in the datacenter evenly across the 2 servers. For example the "pseudo" configuration for **tier2relay-DC1-1** would look like this:

- RELAY_METHOD = consistent-hashing
- DESTINATIONS = server-DC1-1:cache-DC1-1-a, server-DC1-1:cache-DC1-1-b, (...), server-DC1-2:cache-DC1-2-d

---

What I would like to know: how do I tell **tier1relay-DC1-1** and **tier1relay-DC1-2** that they should send all metrics to the *tier2relay*s in DC1 and DC2 (replicate the metrics across the DCs) *and* do some kind of "loadbalancing" between **tier2relay-DC1-1** and **tier2relay-DC1-2**.

---

On another note: I also would like to know what happens inside the carbon-relay if I use consistent hashing, but one or more of the destinations are unreachable (server down) - do the metrics get hashed again (against the reachable caches) or will they simply be dropped for the time? (Or to ask the same question from a different angle: when a relay receives a metric does it do the hashing of the metric based on the list of all configured destinations or based on the currently available destinations?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/grobian/carbon-c-relay

Which exactly does what you need. Also it give you a great boost in performance.

Comment: Thanks! In the mean time we completely overhauled the design and simplified it a little bit. We now have a working cluster with a tier1-carbon-c-relay which replicates to the 2 datacenters and within the datacenter uses fnv1a_ch to distribute the metric to the tier2-carbon-c-relays. The tier2-carbon-c-relays only know the local caches (on the server) and use carbon_ch.